# Android: Draw a picture frame around any size image

Tags: android, xml, imageview, frame, nine-patch

Im basically trying to do this in xml https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/1n_lKanRLjBPkXBr79vES3v3IwR20u5SDvQnbFztb7VOOFRlru6SRTX3RvNsp5PI2w=h900-rw

Anyone know how do it?

Comment: Do you mean a border?

Comment: how would i make a border look like that without using a picture?

Comment: You could use a drawable

Answer (score 0):

You could create a border image for the frame and then use a `FrameLayout` to position the `ImageView` for the frame and the `ImageView` for the picture, setting a `layout_margin` on the picture so that it's inset relative to the frame - e.g.:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/picture_frame" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/picture"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

You might want to think about using a [9patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) `png` for the frame depending on your requirements for scaling it nicely.